# restful sdk for windows 7 in C++ (faster than cpprestsdk)

Tags: windows-7, c++

I need the sdk to be as fast as possible when it sends or receives requests.
The API should be easy to use and it also supports visual studio 2013 and windows 7.

The requirement for this restful sdk is:

1. works for visual studio 2013.
2. supports windows 7
3. can generate json object, parse json string, send requests as client, receive responses as server
4. as fast as it can, as least faster than cpprestsdk
5. API is easy to use

I  have looked into cpprestsdk , restbed and rapidjson. cpprestsdk is pretty usefull but its performance is not the best. Restbed doesn't support httpclient anymore so I cannot use it. RapidJson seems work but its performance doesn't improve too much compare to cpprestsdk and its API is not as good as cpprestsdk. https://blog.binaryspaceship.com/2017/cpp-rest-api-frameworks-benchmark/

Comment: Can you define "as fast as possible"? have you profiled `cpprestsdk`? Or does it just "seem slow" What makes you think that the bottleneck is getiing data in & out of you PC, and not the path it traverses the net, or the time the server takes to process your request? Btw, raw sockets are not difficult to code.